# Issue on Performance testing of H2 database using Jmeter JDBC requests

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, performance-testing, h2, corda

Facing some issue while running the performance testing of H2 database for a corda project.

JDBC requests in Jmeter is used for this testing .
some screenshots of Jmeter is given.

[jdbc connection issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/910hO.png)

[jdbc reruest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxfFD.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YakCp.png)

Comment: I hope you're not planning to go to production with H2; this database is just for development and local testing; you can instead use PostgreSQL with Corda Open Source.

Comment: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-database.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide any error details therefore we cannot come up with the comprehensive solution, going forward make sure to include the screenshot or text of the "Sampler Result" tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and at least the relevant part(s) of the [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) into your question.

The most possible reason is using the wrong [validation query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193190/validation-query), what you supplied is for [Oracle DB](https://www.oracle.com/database/), for H2 you should be using just `Select 1`

Also make sure to put the [H2 JDBC Driver](http://www.h2database.com/automated/h2-latest.jar) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick up the .jar

Check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter/) article for more information on the database load testing using JMeter.

P.S. Be informed that having JMeter and the application under test on the same machine is some form of a performance-testing anti-pattern as both are very resource intensive and in case of CPU/RAM/whatever lack you won't get reliable results.